# How is this webpage updating?

Tags: ajax

Please look at : http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/8592380.stm

The content updates automatically, however, I can't see it doing any ajax requests, so i'm incredibly curious! How do you think it does it?

Sad story though :-(

Thanks.

Comment: What ever they are using, it doesn't seem to work with google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the bottom of the source code there is jason script: http://cdnedge.bbc.co.uk/nol/shared/json/newsid_8590000/newsid_8592300/8592380.json?jsoncallback=bbc.fmtj.net.json.model.getFeedById(0).callback&client=bbcfmtj&cachebuster=cb126985399444464819

I was watching the site in firebug and on update this script "blinked". so thats the one they are using to update as far as i can see

Answer (score 2):

They page is issuing request with javascript. You can see the requests with Firebug plugin.

Comment: I thought it would be that, however, after looking at the page in the firebug plugin there were no ajax requests being called in the console so, naturally, I was rather curious :-)

Comment: Did you choose 'All' in the Net panel? The request appear under 'JS' switch not 'XHR'

Comment: I did not. :-) But I have now. Thanks :-)